# Moving .co.uk to .com for international ecommerce

Tags: domains, internationalization, technical-seo

I am asking for advice please on the best course of action for Shopify site that would like to expand into international markets.

Shopify has the new 'Markets' functionality, where you can easily spin up currencies and languages of markets you would like to enter.

The current site has been running on Shopify for nearly two years on a .co.uk domain, and with lots of effort has most of the targeted keywords in the top 5.

In order to serve these new international markets, Shopify can create subfolders or subdomains for each country you wish to sell to, or by using ccTLD domains for each - but you cannot do the subdomain/folders with a ccTLD - my .co.uk only generic tlds.

I will hopefully get access to the brands .com in due course (another story) and therefore I am asking if it best to:

1. Make the Shopify primary domain .com and 301 redirect all from .co.uk to a subfolder such as website.com/uk/
2. Then add subfolders to the .com for the other markets, such as website.com/fr - website.com/de etc, to keep the structure neat.

Will this 301 to website.com/uk retain most of it's current .co.uk ranking?

Is it even possible to use the Google Move Tool to a subfolder like this?

Should I just use the .co.uk still for the UK market and for all others .com/country?

I will be translating all the content per country into the native languages and I have read Shopify adds the HREFLang tag to each 'market'.

I am really stuck as to the best practice, been all over the forums and usual sites looking for the best way forward, but I am stuck. I would very much like some guidance please from you gurus before I move domains for my shop after all my hard work.

Thank you for your time.